# How to extract child XML using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this XML file called `payload.xml`:

```
<Remoting><Response>
<Controller id="c">
<Messages/>
<StructData name="Root">
    <F name="@ErrorOccured"/>
    <F name="@TransitionErrorOccurred"/>
    <List name="DataList" aspect="Delete"/>
    <List name="DataList" aspect="New">
        <Item name="001">
            <F name="CreationDateTime" >2012/04/26</F>
            <F name="ProductDescription" />
        </Item>
        <Item name="01F">
            <F name="CreationDateTime" >2012/08/09</F>
            <F name="ProductDescription" >Smartphone 16GB</F>
        </Item>                 
        <Header name="@tableSize">316 </Header>
    </List>
</StructData>
<Events>
    <Event event="$Core" operation="$AddRow" path="/Root/DataList"/>
</Events>
</Controller>
</Response></Remoting>
```

And I need to extract this XML from it:

```
<Item name="001">
    <F name="CreationDateTime" >2012/04/26</F>
    <F name="ProductDescription" />
</Item>
<Item name="01F">
    <F name="CreationDateTime" >2012/08/09</F>
    <F name="ProductDescription" >Smartphone 16GB</F>
</Item>
```

My first step is:

```
jQuery.get("payload.xml", function(result){ 
    obj = $(result).find('Response').find('Controller').find('StructData');})
```

When I check inside the debugger I don't see any XML inside `obj`.

Comment: I am not using any namspaces in this one!

Comment: working for me http://jsfiddle.net/JuuPj/

Comment: @Tintin Of course you are. There is an `xmlns="http://test/to"` in all revisions of your questions except the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try lowercasing your tags.

```
jQuery.get("payload.xml", function(result){ 
    obj = $(result).find('response').find('controller').find('structdata');})
```

If that doesn't work, try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/SZxuC/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('Item', result).each(function(){
    $('F',this).text()
});
```